# Sudo inside for loop?

Tags: sudo

In a standard bash shell, I was trying to cat a file from several users' home directories which are on a root-squashed NFS mount so I couldn't just read them as root :

```
sudo -u userA cat ~userA/blah
```

.. works fine. However trying this in a loop doesn't work :

```
for x in userA userB userC; do sudo -u $x cat ~$x/blah; done
```

.. *doesn't* work :

```
cat: ~userA/blah: Permission denied
cat: ~userB/blah: Permission denied
cat: ~userC/blah: Permission denied
```

Now there's other ways to achieve the desired result but what I'm trying to understand is *why* the for loop doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this part is probably not working because of the [order of operations](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/intro).  Tilde expansion happens before parameter expansion, so you are actually trying to a find a file literally named, for example, `~userA/blah` not a file named `blah` in userA's home directory.

You could invoke another shell to get the next round of expansion like

```
sudo -u "$x" sh -c "cat ~/blah"
```

and you shouldn't need to specify the username in the path since you'll already be that user and `~` should be their home dir anyway

Comment: Ah, that does seem to be the issue. Simply changing the command to....   
    _for x in userA userB userC; do sudo -u $x cat /home/$x/blah; done_
   ....is enough to fix it.